# Change DataGridColumn border thickness programmatically

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, code-behind

I'm looking for example how change DataGridColumn border thickness or vertical gridline programmatically in code-behind? Is this possible?

Comment: I would suggest reading into MVVM, its a great way to learn to do this and much much more........https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_first_application.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `CellStyle` to change the vertical grid lines thickness of a `DataGrid`:

```
dataGrid1.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.Horizontal;
Style cellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0)));
cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Black));
dataGrid1.CellStyle = cellStyle;
```

To change the horizontal border thickness you could create a `RowStyle`:

```
dataGrid1.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.Vertical;
Style rowStyle = new Style();
rowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRow.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 5)));
rowStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRow.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Black));
dataGrid1.RowStyle = rowStyle;
```

And this has nothing to do with MVVM. This is view based functionality that belongs to the view.